# Why label still append 0 once press clear button "C"?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am making calculator in swift. Functioning very well so far except the display which is `UILabel`.

I want to get clear out display by pressing `C` button, for that I did this way inside `clear()` I wrote `history.text ="\0"` this is caused append `0` next time when press new digit.

Let me go ahead suppose I presed digit `1 2 * 4` and bottom label display the history every single button been pressed that is `4 * 2 1`.

PROBLEM IS WHEN PRESS C BUTTON TO CLEAR THE 0 STAYS THERE AND NEXT TIME APPEND WITH 0 LIKE 4 * 2 1 0

Download Project all files
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8U2LI6a3maPdmhWVjg4OWREdlE/view?usp=sharing

```
@IBAction func clear() {
        displayValue = 0  //this is about label on top
        history.text = "\(0)"  //this is about label on bottom
}

 @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!

         displayHistory(digit)

        if digit == "." {

            if (display.text!.rangeOfString(".") == nil) {
                display.text = display.text! + "."


            } else {
                //Don't display anything
            }
        }
        else {
                if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
                    display.text = display.text! + digit
                } else {
                    display.text = digit
                    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
                }
        }
    }


 func displayHistory(historyLabel: String) {
            history.text = historyLabel + history.text!
    }
```

Comment: First, you should explain what all the fields are representing. What's `history`? What's `historyLabel`? What's `displayValue`? Then try to think how should every method affect your fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this condition into `displayHistory()` method :

```
if history.text == "0" {
    history.text = historyLabel
}else {
    history.text = historyLabel + history.text!
}
```